# Old IPv6 address does not disappear using another router

Tags: debian, networking, configuration, ipv6

My computer connects to a router via an ethernet cable. I have then an global address IPv6 for example : *a::face/64*. Here is my network configuration at the auto-configuration mode :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

I plug-out the cable then plug it in another router. Logically, the global address of my computer will change to *b::face/64*. But when I used the command "ifconfig", I found that there are both two addresses *a::face/64* and *b::face/64*. Of course, we can't ping6 to the old global address *a::face/64* because it does not really exist.

I tried to fix the problem by changing the configuration from "auto" to "allow-hotplug" but that didn't change much.

My question is : What is the problem of my computer? How can I fix the problem?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in NM, here's the bug report at RedHat's bugtracker (CLOSED WONTFIX): https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=676957

Comment: Is the old address still preferred?

Comment: It may be really a bug. Now everything is normal. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 enabled interfaces have always the link local address that starts with fe80; thus when having another public address, they will have two addresses.

For pinging it, you also have to add to a link local address "%interface_name", so for instance, if eth0 has the IP address `fe80::250:56ff:fe80:45b6` you will have to use:

```
ping6 fe80::250:56ff:fe80:45b6%eth0
```

In ifconfig, you can also see the Scope, and it will be `Scope:Link` for a link local address, and `Scope:Global` for a public IPv6 address.

I will leave the link "Understanding IPv6 Link Local Address"

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/ip-version-6-ipv6/113328-ipv6-lla.html

> These addresses refer only to a particular physical link and are used
>   for addressing on a single link for purposes such as automatic address
>   configuration and neighbor discovery protocol. Link-local addresses
>   can be used to reach the neighboring nodes attached to the same link.
>   The nodes do not need a globally unique address to communicate.
>   Routers will not forward datagram using link-local addresses. IPv6
>   routers must not forward packets that have link-local source or
>   destination addresses to other links. All IPv6 enabled interfaces have
>   a link-local unicast address.

Comment: My question isn't clear, sorry. I'm talking about global address. I will edit my question.